# iPhone XR scaling issue

Tags: ios, iphone, scaling

Here the image of example:

[app-scaled down screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyV5P.png)

**How do I rescale the app to fit to the screen size? Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: First question - Are you using a launch storyboard, if not then do that. If you are, how have you set the constraints on your view?  Have you constrained to the top and bottom edges or have you set a fixed height?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about layout constraints. You add constraints that connect the edges of the view to the edges of the screen, and you're done.